# Best way to update multiple properties of objects in an a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have a function that takes in two parameters and returns an object with those updated parameters as properties

```js
const move = (pos: number, vel: number) => {
  vel += 1;
  pos += vel;
  return { pos, vel };
};
```

I would like to apply this function to an array of classes with the same type of properties

```js
class Obj {
  pos: number;
  vel: number;
  rad: number;
  constructor(pos: number, vel: number, rad: number) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.vel = vel;
    this.rad = rad;
  }
}
```

Here is my current method

```js
const objs = [new Obj(0, 0, 5), new Obj(3, 4, 6)];
objs.forEach((obj) => Object.assign(obj, move(obj.pos, obj.vel)));
console.log(objs); // [ Obj { pos: 1, vel: 1, rad: 5 }, Obj { pos: 8, vel: 5, rad: 6 } ]
```

Are there better ways of doing this, or is `Object.assign` the "accepted" method?

Comment: You haven't provided any criteria for what constitutes "better ways". Either approach is good enough. Just be aware your "out-of-place" is not truly out-of-place: you're still passing `obj` as the first value, so you're changing its property values rather than creating a new object.

Comment: Better approach: make `move` a method of `Obj`, and make it return a new `Obj` instance. (Or, if you actually want to modify your objects in-place, just updates the instance that it's called on).

Comment: @StriplingWarrior oof, thanks for catching that, i'll remove the out-of-place example. I suppose I'm looking for "good enough" methods.

Comment: @Bergi That does indeed work, but I'm trying to keep my update functions as disconnected as possible from the objects themselves.

Comment: @Nevermore Then why are you using `class` syntax if you don't want an OOP approach?

Comment: @Bergi the classes would still have certain methods specific to them, but there are more general functions that I would like to keep as more pure functions.

Comment: @Nevermore When you write "classes", do you mean the plural? What other classes are there? Why are those function "more general", and why do you want to keep them pure if the class instances aren't?

Comment: These probing questions are great. I have classes extending the base class with other properties, certain methods mostly used in the constructor to compute further properties, etc. Upon reflection, I think there's no compelling reason to have these as classes. I could implement them as interfaces and standalone functions as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close because (as it stands) this question doesn't adequately define what would constitute a correct answer, and will likely lead to opinionated answers. I recommend defining in what ways you consider your current approach insufficient, and what attributes you would look for in a "better" approach. If you're just looking for a variety of ideas for improving your code, consider posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: makes sense, apologies for the ill-posed question.